# Google blocking Client API OAuth calls on certain web heads

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-oauth

We have 8 web heads processing request for our web applications.  Starting earlier today, we noticed our Google OAuth stopped working gradually throughout the day. After doing a lot of investigating,  it appears that all but one of the web heads cannot process a Google OAuth request.  For some reason, one server remains able to process request.  No code or network changes have taken place.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: We are getting the 'No data  received' ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in Chrome.

Comment: Ok, we have moved our app to another a brand new server with a brand new IP address and it works find.
Conclusion: it does appear that Google is blocking our IP addresses.  Now, we just have to find out why.

Comment: Ok, more information.  We know we are blocked, we are just trying to get the message back from Google that will hopefully tell us why.

Now, the next problem.  we are using the google-api-php-client and deep inside src/Google/IO/Curl.php the curl_exec is exiting with a 'signal Illegal instruction' and we cannot get access to the return message coming back from Google.

Answer (score 1):

After a solid week of debugging and investigating, we have finally come up with a solution to this issue.

One character change in the Google API PHP Client code, inside the Curl.php, we changed

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
to
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

And all was well.

There seemed to be a issue with this version of curl and https sites dealing with certificates.

**Our environment**

PHP 5.3.3

libcurl 7.19.7-46

google-api-php-client 1.1.5